# Catch values of differents ng-switch in list

Tags: html, angular

I have the switch :

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="compare" >
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Compare </th>
  <!--<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let protocol"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></td>-->
  <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let experiment" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" >
      <ui-switch (change)="onSelect(checked, experiment)" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ui-switch>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

And I want to catch the different value of it. I mean that when I check one here, they all go On.

There is my .ts :

```js
  onSelect(bool: boolean, selectedExp: Experiment){
      if(bool == true){
        if(this.selectedExperiments.length==0){
          this.selectedExperiments[0]=selectedExp.experimentId;
        } else {
          this.selectedExperiments[this.selectedExperiments.length] = selectedExp.experimentId} // because the first table box is 0
        }
        if(bool = false){
          for(var i = 0; i < this.selectedExperiments.length; i++){
            if(this.selectedExperiments[i] == selectedExp.experimentId){
              this.selectedExperiments.splice(i,1); //splice delete the element and reorganize the table
            }
          }
        }
        console.log(this.selectedExperiments);
      }
```

I only want to get the datas of the line I check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `ngSwitch` and follwing way you can implement your case also.

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

For example you have variable `fruit` in your .ts file and based on its value you want to control switch cases and display different `<div>` in your `.html` file.

Then you'll write code as follows:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="apple">APPLE</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="mango">MANGO</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="kiwi">KIWI</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>this is default</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use this.. Could you help me please ?

Comment: @Skimar added an example did it help.

Comment: Not really, I don't see how this would help with my problem.. because my list of experiments implements itself, so I can't make a limited list like this one